# Preventing access to an Excel file wrapped by a Dot.Net application

Tags: .net, winforms, security, office-interop

I have a stand-alone Dot.Net application that wraps and interacts with a Excel file containing secret data, using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Which techniques can I apply in order to protect the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the Excel file is on the client side, **it cannot be protected from reverse engineering**.

## Anything that has keys on the client side may be reverse-engineered.

See these questions on Security SE:

- [Are there DRM techniques to effectively prevent pirating?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/are-there-drm-techniques-to-effectively-prevent-pirating)
- [What role does cryptography play in anti-piracy?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8908/what-role-does-cryptography-play-in-anti-piracy)
- [Excel2007 encryption strength](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17702/excel-2007-encryption-strength)

...and this one on Reverse Engineering SE:

- [Is there any way to decompile a .NET assembly or program?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77/is-there-any-way-to-decompile-a-net-assembly-or-program)